# Документация, уроки. С чего начать?

Tags: golang

Подскажите документацию на русском (предпочтительно)/видеоуроки для начала изучения Go; оставляйте желательно ту информацию, с которой сами начинали.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги, документация, статьи и курсы по Go](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436505/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-go)

Answer (score 2):

Вот очень [хорошая книга](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19954705/), рекомендую

Answer (score 2):

tour.golang.org

Answer (score 0):

+1 За Саммерфельда и еще можно начать с http://archive.miek.nl/projects/learninggo/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Документация, уроки, книги - это все вторично. Делай программы, пусть даже начиная с самых тривиальных, типа "Ввести два числа, вывести их сумму". Нарабатывай опыт. Каждый раз, когда не знаешь, как сделать ту или иную вещь - гуглишь или смотришь в справочник. Вот и все...

```
http://CodeAbbey.com
http://RosettaCode.org
http://users.livejournal.com/_darkus_/
```

Comment: Прямой путь к говнокодерству

Comment: Я буду крайне признателен, если Вы ткнете пальцем в конкретный говнокод - http://www.codeabbey.com/index/user_profile

ИМХО, это вообще понятия ортогональные. Не существует "серебряной пули", будь то язык или книга, которые сделают из говнокодера хорошего программиста. Обратное тоже верно: не существует "говнокодерских" языков, книг или сайтов. Все зависит от человека.

Или Вы хотите сказать, что в гугле можно найти только говнокодерские решения? Там любые есть, вопрос лишь в том, какое выбрать. А для того, чтобы распознать говнокодерское решение, нужен опыт. В том числе и опыт говнокодинга..

Comment: Ссылка повредилась, вот правильная - http://www.codeabbey.com/index/user_profile/vadim-tukaev

Comment: @VadimTukaev

1. Вы экстраполируете свой личный опыт на других
2. Вы принимаете идеи, понятия и принципы, которые родились у вас в результате этого опыта, за единственно верные

Comment: @Etki: Потому что они единственно верные. Почитайте Ильенкова, например. Еще советую книгу Кэрол Дуэк "Гибкое сознание".

Невозможно взять и сразу научиться писать правильно. Знаете, почему в СССР и РФ так мало людей, свободно говорящих на иностранных языках? Потому что в школах требуют заучивать правила, а не говорить. Мол, сейчас научитесь неправильно - потом не переучитесь. Чушь! На курсах люди уже через полгода вполне сносно "шпрехают". Потому что научиться можно только так, путем проб и ошибок. Даже на то, чтобы научиться пользоваться горшком, уходит 2-4 года. А до тех пор - в штанишки..