# Книги, документация, статьи и курсы по Go

Tags: golang, книги, golang-faq

Рекомендуемая литература, документация, статьи и курсы для изучения языка Go.

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Большинство хороших книг и документации по Go, разумеется, на английском языке. Там, где есть переводы, я это указываю. В конце также для удобства отдельно приведен раздел с русскими ссылками, чтобы те, у кого с английским совсем никак, легко могли найти хоть ту немногую информацию, что на русском имеется.

- Чаты и каналы в Telegram

  - [Golang.exe](https://t.me/golang_org) -- канал с интересными материалами по Golang который поможет в изучении данного языка программирования.
  - [4gophers](https://t.me/gophernews) -- канал с обучающим материалом по Golang.
  - [Go (Golang) Дайджест](https://t.me/golangdigest) -- Ежедневные новости из мира Go.
  - [Чат по Golang](https://t.me/golang_talk) -- Популярный чат по Golang в котором обсуждаются нововведения языка и помогают новичкам.
- Официальная документация

  - [A Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org) -- хорошое пошаговое интерактивное руководство, построенное на примерах. Начать можно именно отсюда.
  - [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html) -- пример разработки простого пакета на Go, в процессе которого можно ознакомиться с организацией кода проекта на Go, а также с инструментарием разработчика.
  - [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) -- руководство по написанию чистого, идеоматического кода на Go. Читать обязательно, но после того, как уже есть какое-то представление об языке. Есть [краткий пересказ](http://eao197.narod.ru/desc/short_effective_go.html) на русском языке, но он, к сожалению, не поддерживается в актуальном состоянии.
  - [Frequently Asked Questions](http://golang.org/doc/faq) - часто задаваемые вопросы по Go.
- Другие руководства

  - [Go by Example](https://gobyexample.com/) -- еще одно неплохое руководство, построенное на примерах.
- Книги

  - [C. Doxsey. An Introduction to Programming in Go](http://www.golang-book.com/books/intro) -- неплохая обзорная книга для начинающих, есть [русский перевод](http://golang-book.ru/).
  - [M. Gieben. Learning Go](http://miek.nl/downloads/Go/Learning-Go-latest.pdf) -- еще одна неплохая вводная книга по Go для начинающих.
  - [M. Summerfield. Programming in Go: Creating Applications for the 21st Century](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774639) -- одна из первых бумажных книг по Go, довольно неплохая. Есть [русский перевод](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19954705/), но само качество перевода не очень, много неточностей. Книга легко находится в электронном виде.
  - [A. Donovan, B. Kernighan. The Go programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134190440) -- еще одна бумажная книга по Go, включена сюда из-за имени Кернигана в авторах, с учетом всех его заслуг и того, насколько хороши другие его книги.
- Блоги и статьи

  - [Golangify](https://golangify.com) -- огромное количество актуального учебного материала по Go на русском языке.
  - [The Go Blog](http://blog.golang.org/) -- официальный блог языка.
  - [Golang Planet](http://golang-planet.com/) -- агрегатор блог-постов на тему Go.
  - [Habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/hub/go/) -- хаб по Go на Habrahabr.
- Библиотеки

  - [Awesome Go](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go) -- огромный список фрейморков, библиотек и программного обеспечения, написанного на Go, структурированный по темам.
- Конкурентное программирование

  - [LearnConcurrency](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/LearnConcurrency) -- подборка ссылок для изучения конкурентного программирования на Go.
  - [S. Nilsson. Fundamentals of concurrent programming](https://www.nada.kth.se/%7Esnilsson/concurrency/) -- статья по основам конкурентного программирования с примерами на Go.
  - [Ю. Сердюк. Концепции параллелизма Go](http://b.brainscode.com/2010/01/go.html) -- краткое описание концепции конкурентного программирования в Go на русском.
- Серверное и сетевое программирование

  - [LearnServerProgramming](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/LearnServerProgramming) -- подборка ссылок для изучения программирования на Go на стороне сервера.
  - [J. Newmarch. Network Programming with Go](http://jan.newmarch.name/go/) -- неплохая книга по сетевому программированию на Go.
- Веб-программирование

  - [Writing Web Applications](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) -- статья о написании простого веб-приложения.
  - [Build Web Application with Golang](https://github.com/astaxie/build-web-application-with-golang) -- довольно обширное руководство по Веб-программированию на Go; включает в том числе и краткое введение в сам язык.
  - Mohamed Labouardy — **"Building Distributed Applications in Gin: A hands-on guide for Go developers to build and deploy distributed web apps with the Gin framework"** 2021
- Университетские курсы

  - [Go Courses](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Courses) -- список университетских курсов, использующих Go.

---

- Материалы на русском языке

  *Сюда для удобства также повторно включены русские переводы вышеприведенных материалов*

  - [Краткий пересказ Effective Go на русском языке](http://eao197.narod.ru/desc/short_effective_go.html) -- краткое изложение Effective Go на русском; к сожалению, не обновляется.
  - [К. Докси. Введение в программирование на Go](http://golang-book.ru/) -- неплохая обзорная книга для начинающих.
  - [М. Саммерфильд. Программирование на языке Go](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19954705/) -- одна из первых бумажных книг по Go, довольно неплохая. Русский перевод, к сожалению, не очень качественный. Книга легко находится в электронном виде.
  - [Habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/hub/go/) -- хаб по Go на Habrahabr.
  - Серия статей (довольно старая) на IBM Developer Works:

  1. [Краткий обзор и основы программирования](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-go_01/index.html)
  2. [Разработка Web-приложений](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-go_02/index.html)
  3. [Работа с базами данных](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-go_03/index.html)
  4. [Создание GUI-приложений](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-go_04/index.html)

  - [Ю. Сердюк. Концепции параллелизма Go](http://b.brainscode.com/2010/01/go.html) -- краткое описание концепции конкурентного программирования в Go на русском.
  - [[скринкаст] Погружение в Google Go](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBOo6DBmP5V9CAXxxl6EZxZpMmT_4ZOca) -- вводный курс
  - [[скринкаст] Пишем веб-приложение на Go](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGtcqyFrda9474GltUO-7S4KoJVcdLMp4) -- вводный курс, где рассматривается использование `net/http`, `MongoDB`, `Сессий`, `Авторизации`
  - [[скринкаст] Программирование на Go](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrCZzMib1e9q-X5V9pTM6J0AemRWseM7I) -- 9 лекций от Техносферы Mail.ru
  - [Алан А.А. Донован, Брайан У. Керниган. Язык программирования Go](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/34671680/)  -- Перевод упомянутой ранее книги. ISBN 978-5-8459-2051-5
  - [Батчер Мэтт, Фарина Мэтт. Go на практике](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/139412056/) -- практики использования Go(на примерах 1.7).
  - [Golangify](https://golangify.com) -- огромное количество актуального учебного материала по Go на русском языке.

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая подборка материала. Читал про "Go" еще в другом хорошем посте https://writeabout.tech/programming/want-to-know-everything-go-language/

Answer (score 1):

Переводы:

[Effective Go (RU) (Эффективный Go)](https://github.com/Konstantin8105/Effective_Go_RU)

[Перевод "Руководство сотрудничества"](https://github.com/Konstantin8105/Contribution_Guide_RU)

Answer (score 1):

[Перевод на русский язык официального FAQ языка Go](https://github.com/akrisanov/golang_faq_ru)