# Подборка методов оптимизации математических функций

Tags: математика, оптимизация, машинное-обучение

В связи с увеличивающейся важностью машинного обучения и приближённых методов оптимизации функций потерь, хочется иметь список разных вариантов алгоритмов оптимизации.

Если хотите добавить ещё один метод оптимизации, отредактируйте ответ

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги по теме "Алгоритмы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576507/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Comment: Также: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по фундаментальным знаниям и навыкам разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474416/1365)

Comment: @insolor это не алгоритмы. Это оптимизация.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- [ADAM](https://towardsdatascience.com/adam-latest-trends-in-deep-learning-optimization-6be9a291375c)
- [Метод Недлера-Мида](https://habr.com/ru/post/332092/)
- [Метод имитации отжига](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0)
- [machinelearning.ru: курс](http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Momo)
- [Курс по методам оптимизации](http://bigor.bmstu.ru/?cnt/?doc=MO/base.cou)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/466477)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Я не хочу описывать детали алгоритмов. Я хочу сделать awesome, как это делали для других тем https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436505/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-go/436506#436506